# Alfresco Community v.5.1 does not start and loading the index.html forever

Tags: alfresco

For some unexplained reason I can't use alfresco from yesterday. 
Let me tell you how happens.

First of all, I didn't change any conf file or something like that.
I started tomcat and postgre services and after that, I tried to load "localhost:8080/share" but it was loading forever.
I tried to check the logs files, but no use, too. There is no error messages, nothing unusual.
After that, I deleted alfresco and share folder inside the "webapps", just in case, but it failed, too.
Finally, I can't stop these services from service manager, cause I am at work and I have no access privilege.

My main concern is that I don't even know the cause of this issue, so I don't even know how to ask for help.

Comment: does the database load correctly you need like 150 table if you installed it normally ?!?

Answer (score 2):

When you don't have permission to delete the folder(share + alfresco) and stopping the services also. Without stopping the services, you can't delete the complete files from alfresco and share folders. 
You need to find the problem is in Alfresco share, Alfresco Repo or database or tomcat.

**Check Tomcat**
Type http://localhost:8080 and make sure Tomcat is running or not.

**Check Database**
Connect your database service from Service manager, via PgAdmin tool to check the database service is running or not.

**Check Repo**
http://localhost:8080/alfresco - It should display some basic information about Alfresco Repo otherwise, it is clearly decided the Alfresco Repo itself is failed.

**Check Share**
http://localhost:8080/share - It should display the login page, if everything works fine.

**Logs**
Check and share, alfresco.log, share.log, solr.log, catalina, tomcatstdout and tomcatstderror logs files. Definitely, some of the error information would have recorded any of these logs files.

Comment: The thing was that I couldn't even stop the services. In the end, my noob solution was to restart the pc... After that everything works fine. If you can understand the cause of this problem, i would like to share it.